# JSON file in such each sub dictionary have different key values

Tags: python, json

I have JSON file to read into pandas dataframe with the following dictionary

```
{"ts":1393631983,"visitor_uuid":"04daa9ed9dde73d3","visitor_source":"external","visitor_device":"browser","event_type":"impression","subject_type":"doc","subject_doc_id":"140224195414-e5a9acedd5eb6631bb6b39422fba6798","subject_page":0,"cause_type":"impression"}

{"ts":1393631983,"visitor_uuid":"c08fc48b49f0e1be","visitor_source":"external","visitor_device":"browser","env_type":"reader","env_doc_id":"140206010823-b14c9d966be950314215c17923a04af7","event_type":"pageread","subject_type":"doc","subject_doc_id":"140206010823-b14c9d966be950314215c17923a04af7","subject_page":110}

{"ts":1393631983,"visitor_uuid":"d6e0ca14e08bb49f","visitor_source":"external","visitor_device":"browser","env_type":"reader","env_doc_id":"110727005030-000000009cca70787e5fba1fda005c85","event_type":"pagereadtime","event_readtime":4000,"subject_type":"doc","subject_doc_id":"110727005030-000000009cca70787e5fba1fda005c85","subject_page":14}
```

the thing is each sub dictionary has event_type key and there arw three possibilities :
read
impression
pageread
the next key in the next sub dictionary depend on event_type key
So, when i read the JSON file into pandas dataframe some keys disappears(keys in which not repeated in all subdictionaries
how to split the json depend on event_type

Comment: JSON files must contain exactly one outermost element.  But you've shown us three dictionaries, so this content is not valid json.  Please show us the actual exact contents of the json file.

Comment: @JohnGordon without the empty newlines, this would actually be a valid NDJSON

Comment: I can't quite tell what the question is here. Could you [edit] to pose a clear question?